# Construct Namespaced Xml with Contained XPath Expression

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

I'm attempting to create XQuery code which constructs a namespaced xml element and inserts into it the text from an existing (non-namespaced) element. The following code is a simplified example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $xml := <wrapper><elem>textIWant</elem></wrapper>
return <newElem xmlns="http://www.blah.org">{$xml/elem/text()}</newElem>
```

Instead of producing the desired output:

```
<newElem xmlns="http://www.blah.org">textIWant</newElem>
```

It produces this:

```
<newElem xmlns="http://www.blah.org"/>
```

This code, however, works:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $xml := <wrapper><elem>textIWant</elem></wrapper>
let $elemText := $xml/elem/text()
return <newElem xmlns="http://www.blah.org">{$elemText}</newElem>
```

Using the other form of xml construction (element () {...}) also works fine. The issue only seems to happen when the xml being constructed is being given a namespace. What's the problem with the first code snippet?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing a namespace via the `xmlns` pseudo-attribute changes the default element namespace in the nested XQuery scope. You can get around this by using namespace prefixes,

```
declare namespace ns = "http://www.blah.org";
let $xml := <wrapper><elem>textIWant</elem></wrapper>
return <ns:newElem>{ $xml/elem/text() }</ns:newElem>
```

or using the "any namespace" XPath syntax:

```
$xml/*:elem/text()
```

Comment: This is exactly right.  Rule of thumb: If the code seems right, especially if it works in one context but not another, and you're not getting any result, it's probably namespaces.